# Type 'typeof firestore' has no call signatures nativescript 7 @nativescript/firebase plugin

Tags: firebase, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-firebase

I have a project where I use nativescript with Angular and want to implement Firebase for the back-end. I followed the instructions in the doc of the package and the `firebase.init()` works without errors. But when I want to use the firestore like here:

```
const usernameCollection = firebase.firestore().collection("testUsernames");
```

I get the error:

> This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof firestore' has no call signatures.

I import the module like this:

```
import { firebase } from "@nativescript/firebase";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current import brings in the static types and classes, but not the module itself.

To bring in the module, you need to add `/app` to the end of the path as (poorly) [shown here](https://github.com/eddyverbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/HEAD/docs/FIRESTORE.md).

Wherever you see `"nativescript-plugin-firebase"`, replace it with `"@nativescript/firebase"`.

```
import * as firebase from "@nativescript/firebase/app";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line:

```
import * as firebase from "@nativescript/firebase/app";
```